# Responsive two column social media feed flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set two social media feeds (facebook and twitter) into a flexbox container, set to the middle with space between them. I also want it so that if they don't fit on the page, they should stack on top of each other.

```css
.socialMediaContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 10%;
}

.fb-page {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.twitter {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMediaContainer" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async="1" defer="1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0"></script>
  <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebookappUK/" data-small-header="" data-adapt-container-width="1" data-hide-cover="" data-show-facepile="" data-show-posts="true" data-width="600">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebookappUK/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
      <div id="twitter">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" href="https://twitter.com/Twitter">Tweets by Twitter</a>
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </div>

  </div>
```

What would I need to change about my code to implement this? At the moment, the Facebook feed is in the centre and the twitter feed is on the far right-hand side. Although the twitter feed is responsive, the Facebook feed isn't nad they aren't stacking when it displays. Instead, it just cuts off the feed.

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DcoltGaming/sczxhndr/10/

Comment: Unable to reproduce, blank/white page showed and there are some errors in console. It will be helpful if you can create online demo with JSFiddle

Comment: JSFiffle created. Both feeds are showing but they are not center aligning properly still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSFiddle link you provided is only displaying twitter feeds,
Simple answer for your question is to add `flex-wrap: wrap`.
**Flex wrap** allows flexbox to wrap **next** element/child to bottom of **prev** element/child when there is no enough space. **Example Below**

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

[Demo Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex-wrap)

If this doesn't solve your problem please update the fiddle, So that we can help

**EDIT**
The css properties you are looking for is

```
.socialMediaContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

`justify-content: space-around;` will create space (left and right) to child element and `flex-wrap: wrap;` will wrap the child elements if there is no available space

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/c16hkyvj/2/)

Comment: That works amazingly for making them stack, thank you. The only issue I have left is that the twitter feed is on the far left. I want them in the middle with a small gap between them. I have updated the JSfiddle now as well

Comment: @DcoltGaming Sorry brother my mistake, our comany has blocked facebook and twitter both, but somehow twitter feeds are rendering. Answer Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is missing some closing tags such the `<blockquote>` and the `.fb-page` div.

```
<div class="socialMediaContainer" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async="1" defer="1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0"></script>
  <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/abernightline/" data-small-header="" data-adapt-container-width="1" data-hide-cover="" data-show-facepile="" data-show-posts="true" data-width="600">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/abernightline/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></blockquote>
  </div>
  <div id="twitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" href="https://twitter.com/AberNightline?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by AberNightline</a>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bGNOZeE)

Comment: Thank you, they have been added now